# How do I validate my entities on pressing save button through IDataErrorInfo?

Tags: c#, silverlight, idataerrorinfo

I have implemented `IDataErrorInfo` interface to validate my entities.

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding User.Name, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

It works fine but I want to re-validate the data when the user presses the save button. Is their any way that exists to achieve this functionality in `IDataErrorInfo`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you should consider using INotifyDataErrorInfo Interface

this should give you more control... including a GetErrors method and more which you could execute on the button click command (I asume you are using MVVM)

find Infos here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifydataerrorinfo(v=vs.95).aspx

and a good blog post here:

http://mtaulty.com/CommunityServer/blogs/mike_taultys_blog/archive/2009/11/18/silverlight-4-rough-notes-binding-with-inotifydataerrorinfo.aspx

Answer (score 2):

IDataInfo requires two things to be implemented

1. An indexer property
2. Error property which is null or string.Empty when everyting is OK. Otherwise it is an error description.

If you want to manually validate your entity before saving, you can just check the .Error property and do a save only when .Error is null or empty. I do not know of a way in which the EF could automatically make use of IDataErrorInfo. However when your UI is implemented in the right way, the user shouldn't have the option to save the data until everything is ok. You can implement this using the CanExecuteChanged property of a command (make it true only when .Error is null or empty).